# Prove that the statement of sets is wrong

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do I prove that the following statement is wrong?

> For all non-empty sets $X$ and $Y$ such as $X \subset Y$, for all partitions $P_x$ of $X$ and $P_y$ of $Y$, if $\forall A \in P_x,\, \forall B \in P_y, |A| < |B|$ then $\exists A \in P_x,\, \exists B ∈ P_y, A \subset B$.

Comment: The first step to doing a proof is figuring out exactly what statement you need to prove.  If you write this out as a logical formula, do you know how to negate that formula and move the negation inside all of the quantifiers?

Answer (score 1):

To prove that a statement is wrong, it suffices to find a counterexample.

Take $X = Y = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and consider the partitions $P_X = \bigl\{ \{ 1,4\}, \{2,5\}, \{3,6\}\bigr\}$ and $P_Y = \bigl\{ \{ 1,2,3\}, \{4,5,6\}\bigr\}$. Then the property $$\forall A \in P_X,\, \forall B \in P_Y, |A| < |B|$$
holds. However, no element of $P_X$ is a subset of some element of $P_Y$.